# Make child element fully visible when its bigger than parent

Tags: css

I have a footer div that holds a few divs.  One of which is an image that is taller than the rest and also the footer container.  I'm trying to get the image to show completely, but it is being cut off by the parent div (footer).

Trying to do this with 2 criterias:

1. Footer height to stay as is, and not expand to accomdate the image.
2. Elements inside the footer align on the bottom.

Here's what I have so far..  and the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75asbd6w/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 80%; background: white;">BODY</div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="block-foot-social"> 
            <img src="http://placehold.it/10x10" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/10x10" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/10x10" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/10x10" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/10x10" />
        </div>
        <div class="block-foot-contact">
           <span>1-888-555-5555</span> | <span>Sales@Example.com</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-foot-icon"> 
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
}
.footer {
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
}
.block-foot-contact, .blook-foot-icon, .block-foot-social {
    float: left;
    margin: 6px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.block-foot-icon {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    overflow: visible;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 150px;
}
```

I tried to remove `overflow: auto` from `.footer` but it will collapse the footer div and throw horizontal alignment out of whack.

How would you accomplish this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: so the 80x80 image should... ? what?

Comment: Should be fully visible.

Comment: You mean like: http://jsfiddle.net/75asbd6w/1/ ?

Comment: Not exactly.  Trying to get all child elements in footer to align on the bottom, ideally without expanding the height of the footer to accomodate the 80x80 image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you want the image to display in full but the footer to not expand to fit the height of the image. And everything to align bottom.

Come hither and see my solution:

CSS

```
.footer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}

.block-foot-social,
.block-foot-contact,
.block-foot-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 33.33333%;
}

.block-foot-icon img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

With this solution you will need to change your markup slightly so there isn't any whitespace between the `<DIV>`'s, i.e.

```
<div class="block-foot-social"> 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/10x10" />
    ...
</div><!-- no whitespace here --><div class="block-foot-contact">
    <span>1-888-555-5555</span> | <span>Sales@Example.com</span>
</div><!-- no whitespace here --><div class="block-foot-icon">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
    </a>
</div>
```

You'll also need to make adjustments to the CSS I've posted and provide different widths and margins to the blocks as you desire.